# Работа с DBGrid в Delphi

Tags: delphi, база-данных

Здравствуйте. Я вывожу в `DBGrid` данные из БД через `Table`, но нужно добавить ещё одно поле, и в нём выводить перемноженные данные из двух других полей. Я делаю новое поле (all) у него выбираю `FieldKind` - `fkCalculated`. А вот где выбрать действие с полями и как вывести результат в таблицу?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Зайдите в свойства `TTable` или `TQuery`, в зависимости от того, что используете, во вкладке "События" найдите `onCalcFields`, и там пишите действия что на что умножить.

Answer (score 0):

В событии `Table`-а `OnCalcFields`.